# Unable to scrape data using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

i want to create a catalog using the below code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        tile_container = soup.find("div", id="tileContaine
```

Answer (score -1):

you need add header to request

```
    url = "https://www.coursicle.com/harvard/courses/"
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

your code has another problem is the path of href is relative, you need to get absolute path to visit (you should import urljoin first: from urllib.parse import urljoin)

```
        # Click the link to get the course name
        link.attrs['href'] = urljoin(url, link.get('href'))
        response = requests.get(link["href"])
```